# Get code entered so far in Python interpreter session

Tags: python, shell, command-line, interactive-session

Is there a fast, convenient way to get all the code typed into the python interpreter so far? E.g., if I type this into the interpreter:

```
Steven$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "hi"
hi
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> for e in a:
...   print e
... 
1
2
3
>>> print "bye"
bye
>>>
```

I would like to get these lines:

```
print "hi"
a = [1,2,3]
for e in a:
  print e
print "bye"
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, no, just the source code typed in so far, like in the example output

Comment: do you want the commands saved or to output them from the session?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ideally I would like them output to a file, e.g., out.py

Comment: the dupe should have all you need. The second answer is nice if you are on a unix system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#module-readline) module.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  3 2014, 14:26:24) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "hi"
hi
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> for e in a:
...     print e
... 
1
2
3
>>> print "bye"
bye
>>> import readline
>>> readline.write_history_file('history.py')
```

File `history.py` will contain your history including the last 2 lines:

```
$ cat history.py
print "hi"
a = [1,2,3]
for e in a:
    print e
print "bye"
import readline
readline.write_history_file('history.py')
```

Comment: This works, but for some reason spaces in the output file show up as "\040". Easy enough to fix, but do you know how to prevent this from happening in the first place?

Comment: This seems to be an OSX libedit thing. Sorry, I don't know of a simple preventative fix for it. You could write your own save function that iterates over the available history and replaces `'\040'` with space.

Comment: Does `'\040'` show up when you reload the history file with `readline.read_history_file()`?

Comment: Super easy - it just plain works.  TNX

Comment: can you make it so it only gets this particular sessions history ? This printed 3 or 4 past executions of history.

Answer (score 0):

The %history magic function should do it for you.

```
In [1]: l = [1,2,3]

In [2]: %history
l = [1,2,3]
%history
```

If you find you do this often consider using an [ipython notebook.](http://ipython.org/notebook.html)

Comment: This is what I would do myself, but it's worth mentioning that not everyone uses IPython.

Comment: ah, did not notice he was in non-i python.

Comment: I get a syntax error when using this

Comment: right, it's a command in ipython (a very common python interactive interpreter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370457/what-is-the-difference-between-python-and-ipython ). I haven't used the bare bones interpreter in a long time.

Comment: fwiw: if you are in ipython, you can save your history to a file with the -f parameter, eg %history -f hist.py

Comment: this does not work in standard python.