# Why IPython is much faster than python?

Tags: python, ipython

```
import numpy as np
import time

xyz = np.random.rand(3,2399,2399)
t1 = time.time()
a = []
for _ in range(10):
    a.append((xyz/np.linalg.norm(xyz, axis=0)-np.array([0,0,1])[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis])/3)
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

This is my code. Python 3 run this code in 21.24s while IPython just use 12.6s. What magic does IPython do?

Python 3.6.1

IPython 5.3.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370457/what-is-the-difference-between-python-and-ipython

Comment: more info about differences: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-IPython-and-Python

Comment: I can't reproduce it with Python 3.4.3: same execution time with or without IPython. Are you using some version of Python 2 when running your code outside of IPython?

Comment: @Moyote As those links say, the IPython is just a python shell. I think there should not be any difference in performance.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille No, I use python 3, actually, they all comes from anaconda.

Comment: Anaconda includes numpy with MKL, which can speed up calculations on arrays. Try `np.__config__.show()` and see if it's different between the two.

Comment: IPython is just a shell. How, exactly, are you running these tests?

Comment: python3 script.py and ipython3 script.py