# Python Console lost '>>>' before colon in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, console

Newbie here. I noticed that the `>>>` that usually precedes the colon in the Python Console has been replaced by `In[#]`, in which `#` increments with each command.
I can still run code, but would like to know why this changed, whether it matters, what they mean, etc.

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: That is an IPython repl, instead of the repl that comes with the python interpreter

Comment: [What is the difference between Python and IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370457/what-is-the-difference-between-python-and-ipython) this is not a duplicate but should answer all your questions.

Comment: Btw can be disabled in PyCharm **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Use IPython if available** or by uninstalling IPython if you want so.